# How to make actionButton only work when all inputs are given in R shiny?

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, user-input, action-button

Currently my actionButton is taking in user input through drop down lists, and then when the actionButton is pressed it outputs this to a csv file.
However, if the user only inputs 2 out of the 5 drop down lists and presses the actionButton this will still go to the csv file. How can I make it so it only accepts the actionButton if all inputs are given? I am using observeEvent().

Comment: Take a look at [req](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/req.html). You might want to disable the button until all inputs are filled using [shinyjs](https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the packages `shinyjs` you can deactivate the button when not all inputs are given with something like this.

```
observe(
    {
     if(input$one!=""&&input$two!=""&&!is.na(input$three))
       {
        enable("SubmitButton")
       }
     else
       {
         disable("SubmitButton")
       }
     })
```

just remeber you have to include `useShinyjs()` somewhere in your ui.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `ActionButton` named Submit, after clicking that button you can execute the code, but before the code give an `if` condition that checks if there is any input given.

**In `ui` use:**

```
actionButton(inputId = "SubmitButton",label = "Submit")
```

**In `server` you can use:**

```
 observeEvent(input$SubmitButton,
{
 if(input$one!=""&&input$two!=""&&!is.na(input$three))
   {
    ###You't code involving the multiple inputs
   }
 }
```

Now the code will only work if the Submit Button is pressed and the inputs are not empty or `NULL` based on what you want. I suggest that you initialize the inputs as `""` before in the server section so that this will work Be careful while choosing `input$name!=""` or `!is.na(input$name)`.

In addition to this, you can have a popup if he/she did not fill all the inputs and ask him/her to fill it all by creating a `showModal` in the `server` session.

```
observeEvent(input$SubmitButton,
    {
     if(input$one!=""&&input$two!=""&&!is.na(input$three))
       {
        ###You't code involving the multiple inputs
       }
     else
       {
         showModal(modalDialog(title ="Warning!!!", "Please fill all the fields before you click the Submit buttion!!!"))
       }
     }
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: The first letter in ObserveEvent needs to be lowercase on my system.